# Laravel 4 Controller parameter scope

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-4, undefined

Could you help me figure out why this code does not work:

```
public function getByTag($slug) {

    $posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) {
        $q->where('slug', '=', $slug);
    })->paginate(5);

    return View::make('home')->with('posts', $posts);

}
```

When this does:

```
public function getByTag($slug) {

    $posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) {
        $q->where('slug', '=', 'test');
    })->paginate(5);

    return View::make('home')->with('posts', $posts);

}
```

I simply replaced the $slug in the where() method, because the page breaks with an error saying that $slug is undefined. If I kill the page with die($slug) it returns the correct value, and if, as in my second example, I swap the variable for a static slug value, the page loads the correct posts.

Is $slug inaccesible because I'm in a function that takes new parameters?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getByTag($slug) {

    $posts = Post::whereHas('tags', function($q) use ($slug) {
        $q->where('slug', '=', $slug);
    })->paginate(5);

    return View::make('home')->with('posts', $posts);

}
```

Add `use ($slug)` so $slug will be passed into.

Comment: Spot on again. Thank you!